# How can I configure private network in vagrant box

Tags: vagrant, virtualbox, static-ip-address, private-network

Setup:
On my laptop, I have windows 10 pro install. On that, I have installed latest virtualbox 5.1.2, latest vagrant 1.9.1 and latest packer 0.12.1. My laptop is highend and with strong configuration. I am on wifi.

Purpose:
I want to have three vagrant boxes running Windows 2012 r2 so that I can install SQL server on one, and two different web applications on others.

Success:
Till now I have managed to create vagrant boxes without any hassles. If I use forwarded port method, I am even able to rdp into those machines.

Failure:
My plan is to configure private network for these machines so that they can have their own ip addresses and can communicate with each other. But so far I am unable to achieve so. The private network settings as recommeded on vagrantup.com and other websites do not seem to work for me somehow, as I am sure I am doing some mistake somewhere.

can somebody please help me on how to go about this? I have searched a lot on this site also and gone through many suggestions but none seem to help.

Below is my vagrant file that I am using.

```
Vagrant.configure(2) do |config|

    config.vm.box = "xxxx.box"

    config.vm.communicator = "winrm"
    config.vm.hostname = "xxxserver"    

    # Admin user name and password
    config.winrm.username = "vagrant"
    config.winrm.password = "vagrant"

    config.vm.guest = :windows
    config.windows.halt_timeout = 600
    config.vm.network "private_network", ip: "192.168.50.4"

end
```

And below is the error message that I get when I run vagrant rdp
*

> ==> default: Detecting RDP info... RDP connection information for this machine could not be detected. This is typically caused when we can't
>   find the IP or port to connect to for RDP. Please verify you're
>   forwarding an RDP port and that your machine is accessible.

*

But if I replace

```
config.vm.network "private_network", ip: "192.168.50.4"
```

with

```
config.vm.network "forwarded_port" , host: 33390 , guest: 3389
```

and then reload the box then vagrant rdp works fine and I am able to loginto it. I want to use static ips for my vms.

Kindly guide..
thanks.

Comment: can somebody help me with this please?

Answer (score 0):

I also use a private_network with a static ip. Only adding (not replacing) the line `config.vm.network "forwarded_port" , host: 33390 , guest: 3389` works.

```
$ vagrant rdp
==> fe: Detecting RDP info...
    fe: Address: 127.0.0.1:33389`enter code here`
    fe: Username: vagrant
==> fe: Vagrant will now launch your RDP client with the connection parameters
==> fe: above. If the connection fails, verify that the information above is
==> fe: correct. Additionally, make sure the RDP server is configured and
==> fe: running in the guest machine (it is disabled by default on Windows).
==> fe: Also, verify that the firewall is open to allow RDP connections.
```